# Margins, padding and borders not displaying correctly in web page

Tags: html, css, border, padding, margins

I'm creating a skeleton web site as part of an assignment, and I have a problem with margins, padding and borders. I believe it's because I'm using an old standard of CSS, but I'm not entirely sure.

I've included a screenshot of one of the web pages, and the CSS code, in the hope that someone will come to my rescue.

Thanks in advance. :)

[image]

```
*, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;  
}

body {
    margin: 0 px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    background-color: #B8B8B8;
}

h1 {
    height: 80 px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #003366;
    text-align: right;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 32 px;
    margin: 0 px;
}

#nav {
    height: 50 px;
    background-color: #336699;
    text-align: left;
    color: white;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16 px;
    border-bottom: thin solid Black;
    padding: 16 px;
    margin: 0;
}

#nav ul {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0px;
}

#nav li {
    display: inline;
}

#nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 16px 16px 16px 16px;
}

#nav a:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: #000000;
}

#nav a:active {
    background-color: white;
}

h2 {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#body {
    background-color: White;
    border: thin solid Black;
    padding: 1 em;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-right: 1%;
    height: auto;
}

#footer {
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: x-small;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand you correctly, you want the text to not touch the borders.

Start with adding a value to you margin like so

```
 *, html {
   margin: 10 px;
   padding:25 px ;}
```

of course this is an example you have to match them the way you like.

I include a couple of code blocks, I hope they help you understand the difference between padding and margin.

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css1.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <header>abc</header>
</body>
</html>
```

css

```
body {
margin-left : 25px;
margin-right: 20px;
padding: 10px;
border: dotted;
```

}

Comment: I've sorted it now :) Thank you!